# Ошибка при сборке maven unable to find attribute

Tags: java, maven

В чем может быть ошибка? Собираю проект apk через maven.

```
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex 
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColor, unable to find attribute android:endX
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColorItem, unable to find attribute android:offset
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте определить **googlePlayServicesVersion="15.0.1"**.

См. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/694#issuecomment-503003910